# Django cannot find all my files in static files

Tags: python, django

I'm totally fresh to Django. I downloaded a template that presents a well-structured web page. But after I put all the template files in the static dir, it didn't show any images or run any js/CSS files.
Here is my dir:[image: **enter image description here**]

Here is my settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles']


# URL prefix for static files
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Absolute path to the directory in which static files should be collected
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'root')

# Additional locations for static files (optional)
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),]
```

This is what I got at terminal:

```
[31/May/2020 07:55:02] "GET /static/assets/vendor/aos/aos.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1699
[31/May/2020 07:55:02] "GET /static/assets/vendor/owl.carousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1786
[31/May/2020 07:55:02] "GET /static/assets/vendor/icofont/icofont.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1735
[31/May/2020 07:55:02] "GET /static/assets/vendor/boxicons/css/boxicons.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1753
[31/May/2020 07:55:02] "GET /static/assets/vendor/venobox/venobox.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1723
[31/May/2020 07:55:02] "GET /static/assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1759
[31/May/2020 07:55:03] "GET /static/assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1726
[31/May/2020 07:55:03] "GET /static/assets/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1684
[31/May/2020 07:55:03] "GET /static/assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1774
[31/May/2020 07:55:03] "GET /static/assets/vendor/jquery.easing/jquery.easing.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1768
[31/May/2020 07:55:03] "GET /static/assets/vendor/php-email-form/validate.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1744
[31/May/2020 07:55:03] "GET /static/assets/vendor/waypoints/jquery.waypoints.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1765
[31/May/2020 07:55:03] "GET /static/assets/vendor/counterup/counterup.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1744
[31/May/2020 07:55:04] "GET /static/assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-9.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1732
[31/May/2020 07:55:04] "GET /static/assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-8.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1732
[31/May/2020 07:55:04] "GET /static/assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-2.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1732
[31/May/2020 07:55:04] "GET /static/assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-7.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1732
[31/May/2020 07:55:04] "GET /static/assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-5.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1732
[31/May/2020 07:55:04] "GET /static/ssets/img/portfolio/portfolio-4.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1729
[31/May/2020 07:55:04] "GET /static/assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-6.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1732
[31/May/2020 07:55:05] "GET /static/assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-1.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1732
[31/May/2020 07:55:05] "GET /static/assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-3.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1732
[31/May/2020 07:55:05] "GET /static/assets/vendor/isotope-layout/isotope.pkgd.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1768
[31/May/2020 07:55:05] "GET /static/assets/vendor/venobox/venobox.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1732
[31/May/2020 07:55:05] "GET /static/assets/vendor/owl.carousel/owl.carousel.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1762
[31/May/2020 07:55:05] "GET /static/assets/js/main.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1675
[31/May/2020 07:55:05] "GET /static/assets/vendor/php-email-form/validate.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1744
[31/May/2020 07:55:05] "GET /static/assets/vendor/aos/aos.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1696
[31/May/2020 07:55:06] "GET /static/assets/vendor/venobox/venobox.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1732
[31/May/2020 07:55:06] "GET /static/assets/vendor/owl.carousel/owl.carousel.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1762
[31/May/2020 07:55:06] "GET /static/assets/vendor/aos/aos.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1696
[31/May/2020 07:55:06] "GET /static/assets/js/main.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1675
```

The web page is supposed to like this:
[image]

And now it looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Tell us what errors you see in the browser console. My guess is it is using the wrong URL for styles etc.

Comment: @Ronald Well it doesn't show any error. Just the images doesn't show on my web page. And I also add {% load static %}
{% load staticfiles %} in my html corresponding to the web pages. I have used the collactstatic command too, it worked well.  But the images still didn't show up.

Comment: It looks like the CSS is missing so check the network tab in the browser's dev / inspector. Are there no failing requests there?

Comment: @Ronald I  found out what's the problem! I put the static file at the wrong place. It should have under the project directory .It should have the same parent folder as templates. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

you should follow your url from static directory of each folder you have created by {% static......%}

example from css folder

this is what you will do for img, lib, folders also

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).